# How to simplifying and solving this polynomial?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, factoring

I have a problem with simplifying the polynomial. In the first time, I see that this polynomial is quite simple, but when I'm trying, I realized that this polynomial isn't as easy as I saw.

Here is the problem:

\begin{eqnarray} \left(x^3-x^2y-2xy^2-x^2+8xy-6x\right) \leq0\\\end{eqnarray}

My attempt:
First I isolated x, so that x is outside this equation:

\begin{eqnarray} \left(x(x^2-xy-2y^2-x+8y-6)\right) \leq 0\ \end{eqnarray}

Then, I'm trying to find the variables that can I modify, such that the equation can be simplify like this:
\begin{eqnarray} \left(x(x^2-2xy+xy-2y^2-x+8y-6)\right) \leq 0\ \end{eqnarray}

Until this equation, I cannot go any further.

Can anybody help me to continue this problem and find its solution?

And, also what is the easiest way to simplify this kind of this problem?

Thanks

Comment: For future reference, you can use \leq for the less than or equal to sign.

Comment: @A.Wong, yes, <= mean less than or equal to. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for $a,b,c,d$ such that:
$$x^2−xy−2y^2−x+8y−6 = (x+a y+b)(x+cy+d) \\ = x^2+(a+c)xy+(ac)y^2+(b+d)x+(ad+bc)y+bd$$

So solve: $\left[\begin{array}{rcl}a+c&=&-1\\ac&=&-2\\b+d&=&-1\\ad+bd&=&+8\\bd&=&-6\end{array}\right] \implies a= 1,b=-3, c=-2, d=2$

$$\therefore x^2−xy−2y^2−x+8y−6 = (x+ y-3)(x-2y+2)$$